# How to include RSI and Volume in the same chart?

Tags: json, charts, highcharts, candlestick-chart

First of all i want to embed RSI plugin with the highstock chart, 
(i.e) RSI, Volume in the same chart. i tried it with using  Highstock
**(Two panes, candlestick and volume )**

```
http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume
```

and the RSI indicator plugin

```
http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/RE7sS/
```

Any ideas to get it done??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add RSI to any Highstock demo, you need to include required files. In RSI case files are:

- indicators.js (base)
- ema.js (required for RSI)
- rsi.js (RSI plugin)

And example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/jLpbL1db/

Note:

Don't forget to add indicator in options, with link to `series.id`:

```
        indicators: [{
            id: "AAPL",
            type: "rsi"
        }],
```

Comment: Fus can we add events to the above code? if so how can we add custom events in the candlestick ??

Comment: Which events? Could you specify?

Comment: Fus thanks for your response. i have added custom events already now i have another issue, which is already down voted in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26686963/phphighcharts-candlestick-volume-and-rsi-data-missing) can you please give solution