# PHP::Highcharts candlestick volume and rsi data missing

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts, volume, candlestick-chart

i am working highcharts candlestick with volume and rsi indication.

when i put **indicators.js** in my page, lot of data missing in chart but it showing on volume.

If suppose i remove **indicators.js**, all data perfectly showed on both chart and volume but rsi indicator not working.

I want to show all data on both chart and volume with rsi indication.

data format - json [prepared dynamically from mysql and php]

Anybody knows let me know.

JS Fiddle Link [For Demo]

```
<http://jsfiddle.net/pandymassblack/sto92yvw/6/>
```

Comment: Could you create jsFiddle demo with that issue? It's hard to say what is wrong without seeing this.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
Pls check the [fiddle link]
(http://jsfiddle.net/pandymassblack/sto92yvw/6/)
My [Demo Url]
(http://jesmoinfotech.com/development/eqsis/test.php)

Comment: For me it looks like you are using old version of indicators (download latest version from github). Anyway, on your chart I can see line, volume and RSI (with bug, fixed in latest release).