# Can I add custom data for highcharts RSI indicator?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am looking way when I be able to add own data for RSI indicator..
On picture RSI indicator which i can add using next code lines:

```
id: 'AAPL',
type: 'rsi',
params: {
   period: 14,
   overbought: 70,
   oversold: 30
   },
```

[image]

But if I decide to calculate RSI data on server side .. and send back to highcharts I must build new highcharts, but maybe exist way when I can add custom indicator with my data for current highcharts ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include RSI and Volume in the same chart?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26250952/how-to-include-rsi-and-volume-in-the-same-chart)

Comment: @Venkatraman no, the post show how to include RSI and Volume in the same chart.. - i know this, I am looking - how to include RSI and Volume in the same chart + RSI with custom data

Comment: Refer this for sample data. http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/ywvhx/

Comment: @Venkatraman it can be like custom indicator ... but i can't include this to current highcharts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the indicators plugin, RSI is calculated automatically, so you cannot set yoru own points. When you have your own values (calculated in back-end) then you should add extra serie with defined yAxis.

Example:

- http://www.highcharts.com/demo/synchronized-charts